# After set up local network through router internet is slow

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

We have at home network with 3 computers (2 win, 1 mac os). The internet goes to all computers through router. The problem is, that the websites are loaded too slowly, sometimes ever are not loaded.

When I download some data from torrents, the download speed is 1-2MBit/s (our internet connection si 25MBit/s), but the speed of a webpages is awful, incredible slowly.

I would like to ask you, where could be a problem, something wrong with DNS translation, or bad setup of router?

I don't really familiar with the networks and stuffs around, but trying to find a solution of this problem already third day and still without success.

Comment: It is possible your ISP is using traffic shaping because of your torrenting (it is extremely common now). Use this website to test both HTTP and Torrent protocols for traffic shaping:
http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php

Comment: the torrenting I mentioned only as an example. This loading pages is slow also if I don't download anything... that's the problem.

Comment: Traffic shaping can adversely affect your connection for the duration of an entire billing period, it does not necessarily have to happen at the same time as you are downloading. I.e. they often limit your connection all the time if they believe you are torrenting.

Comment: What router do you use? A weak router CPU may limit the maximum traffic. How many simultaneous TCP connections do you have open on all three computers?

Comment: I had one really, really old router, but it stopped work. So I friend of mine borrowed me his (some ASUS) - and I had the problem described above. Then I bought my new router - **TP-LINK TL-WR841ND**, and the same problem. What do you mean about TCP connections? On each computer is ran only browser, nothing more...

Comment: Didn't you find a solution? I have the same problem but with **TP-LINK TL-WR841N** .I suppose that something is wrong with DNS, because some sites like gravatar.com, drupal.org and others from time to time cannot be found.